# Python Request Module - TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, request

I am getting Error from Requests Module.
My same code was working few days back, But its not working anymore.

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 469, in send
            for i in request.body:
        TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Python=3.8

requests=2.22.0

Full Code

```
C:\Windows\system32>python
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json, requests
>>> from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
>>> url = "https://mywebsite.com/"
>>> auth = HTTPBasicAuth("username", "password")
>>> headers = { "Accept": "application/json","Content-Type": "application/json"}
>>> tickets_created = []
>>> payload = json.dumps
>>> (
...     {
...         "fields":
...         {
...         "project":
...             {
...             "key": "PROJECT_A"
...             },
...         "summary": "summary",
...         "description": "desc",
...         "issuetype":
...             {
...             "name": "Incident",
...             },
...         "components":
...     [{"name":"Active Directory" }],
...         "assignee":
...             {
...             "name":"aashutosh.kumar@mywebsite.com"
...             }
...        }
...     }
... )
{'fields': {'project': {'key': 'PROJECT_A'}, 'summary': 'summary', 'description': 'desc', 'issuetype': {'name': 'Incident'}, 'components': [{'name': 'Active Directory'}], 'assignee': {'name': 'aashutosh.kumar@mywebsite.com'}}}
>>> response = requests.request("POST",url,data=payload,headers=headers,auth=auth,verify=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 469, in send
    for i in request.body:
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
>>>
```

Comment: This isn't a [mre] so I don't see how we can help.

Comment: @RandomDavis, Added full code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're setting `payload = json.dumps` - all the lines after it are *not* being passed to `dumps()`. Do this instead (putting the open parenthesis on the same line):

```
payload = json.dumps(
    {
        "fields":
        {
        "project":
            {
            "key": "PROJECT_A"
            },
        "summary": "summary",
        "description": "desc",
        "issuetype":
            {
            "name": "Incident",
            },
        "components":
    [{"name":"Active Directory" }],
        "assignee":
            {
            "name":"aashutosh.kumar@mywebsite.com"
            }
       }
    }
)
```

Comment: It Worked, Thank you.
But I am still Concerned, because My same code was working few days back.

Comment: @Aashutosh if it was working before, something about it _must_ have been different.

Comment: Only Difference is, I was using this piece of code in a function, To debug something, when I am using this independently, It was giving error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the variable `auth` that you are using is a function and not a tuple or list.

The docs for [`requests.request()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.request) say:

> :param `auth`: (optional) Auth tuple to enable Basic/Digest/Custom HTTP Auth.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
requests.post(url,data=payload, headers=headers, auth=auth, verify=False)
```

Comment: Can you delate auth and verify?

Comment: Problem is identified, Issue is the json.dumps Opening Bracket.
Since I have SSL Certificate Error at Target Site, I have to use verify=False